# Need to convert CRT files from Sectigo (Comodo) to pfx for azure

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate

I bought a Sectigo's SSL Certificate from an intermediate vendor. I requested to vendor the certificate and Sectigo send me the four crt certificates (root, intermediates, ssl). I want to convert to pfx for azure but I dont have either private key and scr data. Can I convert the certificates or I need to request the private and/or crt data to the intermediate vendor

Answer (score -2):

In the IIS you create a certificate request. As soon as you receive the CRT run the following commands  in cmd

type  DomainNAme.crt AAACertificateServices.crt USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt>Domain.cer

Go to complete certificate request and import the domain.cer . Then from IIS you can export the pfx.

Answer (score -3):

I request to my intermediate vendor the private key and I can generate pfx file!!!

Comment: If anyone else besides you has the private key then you should immediately ask to revoke this certificate, not use it and generate a new one, where you control the private key. Otherwise you are vulnerable to the third party identify as yourself.